# How to make the height of two rows 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a website that visualizes data. The page should **resize itself** according to the **screen size** (NO mobile optimization, just different laptop/pc screen sizes) and everything should be visible without scrolling (exception: scrollbars are allowed inside containers'). It should look like the following:

[image]

With a lot of googling and trying, I came this far:

```
I didn't post any code in here, because it would become not
readable in this post. But I pasted the code into jsfiddle
where you can see my current state:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/casaout/239DX/1/

Unfortunately, I still have some issues:

- In the right column, the visualization **height of the "visualization" frame should be dynamical** (probably a fixed min-height). The two "node details" and "log" frames should stay 300px high and get a **scrollbar if they get higher**. Unfortunately, both of this 'wishes' currently don't work.
- In the left column, the five containers should resize themselves (all together should be 100% high). I tried several things (like min-height, percentages, etc.), but couldn't make it work.

What am I doing wrong? - **Thank you so much** for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the fixed height and scrollbar is concerned, here a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1/

**CSS**

```
.FixedHeightContainer
{
  float:right;
  height: 250px;
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
    background:#f00;
}
.Content
{
  height:224px;
   overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
   // lot of text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Ali Gajani
Thank you very much for your answer. This helped me to fix the first problem.

Comment: Now let me help you with the second one, so what is it? I am a bit confused, what do you want to do with visualization frame?

Comment: Edit: I could solve both of my problems. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, sense you're dealing with responsive height. However, most of this can be achieved with jQuery.

Use `.outerHeight()` to get the window height, `$(window).outerHeight`. Once you have the height what you're working with, you can then assign the heights (ratio) to the blocks within it.

And if the user resizes the window after the page has loaded, you can detect that with `$(window).on('resize', function() { ... });`

Does this help or do you need me to work with your example?